# MDIChild toolbar displays in MDIParent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have an MDIChild that has a toolstrip.  When I open the window the toolstrip is displayed alongside the toolstrip of the MDIParent.  The searching I have done suggests that this is normal behaviour unless the child is opened modally.  Can I not stop this from happening and fix the toolstrip to the window it is meant to be displayed on?

[image: MDI Parent]
This is the MDI Parent

[image: MDIChild]
This is the MDI Child

[image: MDI Child Open]
This is what happens when I open the child and what I want to stop happening.

Comment: Simply set the MenuStrip's AllowMerge property to False in the child form.  This is uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `AllowMerge` Property of the MenuStrip of the Child form to false.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.allowmerge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Use the AllowMerge property to enable multiple-document interface (MDI) children to combine their respective menus in the MDI parent.

When this property is set the true, the menus will combine (just like in your case). When false, they won't